# linear algebra permutation matrix question?

Tags: linear-algebra

There are 12 "even" permutations of (1, 2, 3, 4), with an even number of exchanges. Two of them are (1, 2, 3, 4) with no exchanges and (4, 3, 2, 1) with two exchanges. List the other ten. Instead of writing each 4 by 4 matrix, just order the numbers.

Comment: What have you tried? Which of the remaining ten have you found?

Comment: (1234)(4321)(2143)(3412)(2314)(1423)(4132)(3241)(1342)(4213)(2431)(3124) I don't know how to find efficiently.

Comment: Is listing all permutations and taking every other not efficient enough?

Comment: @paperskilltrees That will be too unwise. I believe there is good reasoning. The solution is (3, 1, 2, 4) and (2, 3, 1, 4) keep 4 in place; 6 more even P’s keep 1 or 2 or 3 in place;
(2, 1, 4, 3) and (3, 4, 1, 2) and (4, 3, 2, 1) exchange 2 pairs. (1, 2, 3, 4) makes 12. I don't understand "6 more even P’s keep 1 or 2 or 3 in place".

Comment: @YaoZhao I think for every practical purpose you've solved the problem, at least as it was stated. Try to formulate precisely what your question is and what is that you don't understand. Perhaps, you could read Wikipedia article about permutations first, in order to be able to use the right terminology. Read about [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) in particular. I guess, what you are looking for is in this direction.